# MVC 3 get list from JSon

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am sending form values to controller via JSON. I get all values at controller. But when i send a list, list items are always null. I dont know what the problem is.
Here is my view model :

```
public class PromotionLineViewModel
{
    public string PromotionID { get; set; }
    public ConditionList[] ConditionList { get; set; }
    public string ItemUsageType { get; set; }
    public string PriceCalculationType { get; set; }
    public string PromotionDiscount { get; set; }
    public string LimitCheck { get; set; }
    public string MinQuantity { get; set; }
    public string MinAmount { get; set; }
    public string MaxQuantity { get; set; }
    public string MaxAmount { get; set; }
    public string IsActionActive { get; set; }
    public string ActionQuantity { get; set; }
    public string ActionFixed { get; set; }
    public string BundleGroupNr { get; set; }
    public string PalletQuantity { get; set; }
    public string ProductUsageMultiplier { get; set; }
    public string MaxCapAmount { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ConditionList
{
    public string check { get; set; }
    public string isExclude { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my jquery code :

```
function dataPost(url) {
var formData = form2object('prm-form', '.', true);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("done");
    }
});

//$.post(url, formData,"json");
//   document.getElementById('testArea').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(formData, null, '\t');  
//}
```

and this is what i get :

[Controller Image](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/1784/adszbpd.png)

I already checked json values. They all come correctly. I need to get list items values at controller.
Here is my json format :

```
{
"PromotionID": "000004",
"ConditionList": [
    {
        "check": "12",
        "isExclude": "0",
        "value": "2334"
    },
    {
        "check": "13",
        "isExclude": "1"
    }
],
"ItemUsageType": "1",
"PriceCalculationType": "1",
"PromotionDiscount": "234",
"LimitCheck": "0",
"MinQuantity": "2",
"MinAmount": "2",
"MaxQuantity": "2",
"MaxAmount": "2",
"IsActionActive": "action",
"ActionQuantity": "2",
"ActionFixed": "fix",
"BundleGroupNr": "2",
"PalletQuantity": "2",
"ProductUsageMultiplier": "2",
"MaxCapAmount": "2"
}
```

Controller action :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult JsonResult(PromotionLineViewModel promotionLineViewModel)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: What  does your controller action look like?

Comment: Why is you action called `JsonResult`? So what is the problem, you're not getting the values on the server side? Or the server is not returning the values back to the client. I would also decorate the `PromotionLineViewModel` as `Serializable`

Comment: What's `form2object`? Why don't you use `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: DefaultModelBinder cannot deserialize composite object from JSON out of the box. You need to write custom ModelBinder for this.

Comment: @Gabe i m getting values except List values. At debug mode ConditionList[] count is correct but as i said it fails to get list item values. JsonResult is just a name by the way :) Not the class one.

Comment: @Darin we are 2 person working in this project. Other guy is a javascript expert. He wrote this function to collect form values.

Comment: @ Kirill Bestemyanov, you don't need to do that in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
public List<ConditionList> ConditionList { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public ConditionList[] ConditionList { get; set; }
```

as shown below:

```
public class PromotionLineViewModel
{
    public string PromotionID { get; set; }
    public List<ConditionList> ConditionList { get; set; }
    public string ItemUsageType { get; set; }
    public string PriceCalculationType { get; set; }
    public string PromotionDiscount { get; set; }
    public string LimitCheck { get; set; }
    public string MinQuantity { get; set; }
    public string MinAmount { get; set; }
    public string MaxQuantity { get; set; }
    public string MaxAmount { get; set; }
    public string IsActionActive { get; set; }
    public string ActionQuantity { get; set; }
    public string ActionFixed { get; set; }
    public string BundleGroupNr { get; set; }
    public string PalletQuantity { get; set; }
    public string ProductUsageMultiplier { get; set; }
    public string MaxCapAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method directly. So if we suppose that you have a form with `id="prm-form"`:

```
function dataPost(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $('#prm-form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("done");
        }
    });
}
```

In this case you don't need to send JSON. It's easier than that.